# Confusion about sum of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V,W$ be subspaces of vector space $U$ where $U=V+W$. Now, my question is if it is true that if $X$ is a subspace of U, then $X=(X\cap V)+(X\cap W)$?

I think this should be true since the direct sum $V\oplus W$ is a smaller set than $V+W$ which covers the space U. Could someone please help prove or counterexample for why this is or isn't always true? Thanks.

Comment: It's not true, take for example three different lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @mathim1881 The claim is false with a very simple counterexample: for any field $K$, you have the direct sum decomposition $K^2=K \times \{0_K\}+\{0_K\} \times K$. The diagonal $\Delta_K$ is a one-dimensional subspace which has however the property that $\Delta_K \cap \left(K \times \{0_K\}\right)=\Delta_K \cap \left(\{0_K\} \times K\right)=\left\{0_{K^2}\right\}$.

Comment: @mathim1881 One more remark: the direct sum of two subspaces $U$ and $W$ will not in general be a subspace of your given ambient space. The direct sum has a very specific definition and is a very specific construction. In general, there exists a surjective morphism from the direct sum $U \oplus W$ *onto* the sum $U+W$, the latter being indeed a subspace by definition.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615905/is-any-subspace-of-a-direct-sum-necessarily-a-direct-sum-of-subspaces?rq=1

Comment: @ArnaudD. thanks very much, this is very clear and has helped me understand an important characteristic of vector spaces I was misunderstanding